# accessing neo4j database in DigitalOcean droplet

Tags: neo4j, digital-ocean

I followed this tutorial for setting up a neo4j database on digital ocean: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-neo4j-on-an-ubuntu-vps, which basically amounts to apt-get install neo4j.

How can I access the browser for this database?

Answer (score 4):

Once you've successfully installed neo4j on the server make sure that the server configuration allows connection to the web console on all ips (remote, local). You can achieve that by editing the file located at:

> **/etc/neo4j/neo4j-server.properties**

and making sure that this line looks like the following one:

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
```

save the file and restart the neo4j server and from your browser:

> http://YOUR_SERVER_IP:7474